# Advanced request in waterline (sails, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have the Video model (Waterline)

**Video**

```
  -title
  -description
  -matches (array)
    [0]
      - MatchTitle
      - MatchDescription
    [1]
       ...
    [N]
```

How can I find videos which contains matches with title "ABC" for example ?

I wrote not the best solution, because it retrive all data from database

```
Video.find({is_html5:true}).done(function(err, videos) { // get all videos
  async.forEach(videos, function(video, callback) {
    var isFound = false;
    async.forEach(video.matches, function(videoMatch, matchCallback) { // get video matches
      if(videoMatch.gs_id === match.gs_id && !isFound) {
        match.relatedVideos.push(video.id);
        isFound = true;
      }
      matchCallback();
    }, function(err3) {
      callback();
    });
  }, function(err2) {
    cb();
  });
}, function(err1) {
  cb();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to use some mongo's magic and find Video by array item's property?

```
Video.find({'matches.matchTitle' : 'ABC'}).exec(...);

// or using regex (if you want to match a substring)
Video.find({'matches.matchTitle' : { $regex: /ABC.*/ }}).exec(...);
```

How that helps.